# Google Cloud Platform Change Ubuntu Kernel to generic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, kernel, google-cloud-platform

It is possible to change google cloud vm kernel?

I created  Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with kernel GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1030-gcp x86_64 machine.

I downloaded  4.4.0-146-generic

I tried to change the /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_DEFAULT value and reboot 
but till the machine start with the gcp kernel

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Grub config in /etc/default/grub GRUB_DEFAULT is overridden by the following file in GCP.

Edit :  /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg

GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"

update-grub

reboot

VM will boot with generic kernel.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to install a kernel module that seems to not be available, try looking for a customized gcp module instead. So for example to install ALSA loopback on a GCP VM that has `5.15.0-1021-gcp` kernel, instead of going back to whatever generic kernel like `5.4.0-whatever-generic` and then installing `linux-modules-extra`, go for

```
apt install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1021-gcp
```